# python: copy+paste apostrophe from internet gives me a strange error

Tags: python, string, utf-8, ascii

I need to be able to use copy+pasted strings from a website in my code. The website's encoding is unicode (utf-8). The string

```
'''I’ve held others before'''
```

is copy+pasted and has a 'funny' apostrophe. When I try to replace this apostrophe

```
my_string = '''I’ve held others before'''

my_string.replace('’', "'")
print(my_string)
```

I still get

```
>>> I’ve held others before
```

instead of

```
>>> I've held others before
```

I cannot use the string with the funny apostrophe because later on in my code it gives me this error:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried adding both

```
my_string.decode('utf-8')
my_string.encode('utf-8')
```

but they don't seem to do anything. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the encoding of the page from which you pasted the string?

Comment: I think unicode (utf-8). http://www.poemsource.com/love-poems.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable in python, you need to assign back the result of `str.replace` to the variable again.

```
>>> my_string = '''I’ve held others before'''
>>> my_string = my_string.replace('’', "'")
>>> my_string
"I've held others before"
```

It's better to use `u'...'` prefix for unicode strings:

```
>>> u'''Joey’s house'''.replace(u'’', "'")
"Joey's house"
```

Add this line at the top of your file to remove those decoding errors:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```